# How to use microsoft cognitive api for emotion detection in faces?

Tags: javascript, api, face, emotion

I am trying to detect emotions in faces from an image uploaded. I can't seem to find any example code for emotion detection.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/cognitive-services/my-apis/?apiSlug=face-api&country=Canada&allowContact=true

I found this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/quickstarts/javascript

but the url endpoint doesn't work. I then tried regular face api, but even that I get `resource not found`.

Does anyone know what's going one?

Thanks

```
var FACE = new function () {

    this.listen = function() {

        var camera = document.getElementById('camera');

        camera.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var imageFile = e.target.files[0];     
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var fileType;

            //wire up the listener for the async 'loadend' event
            reader.addEventListener('loadend', function () {    
                //get the result of the async readAsArrayBuffer call
                var fileContentArrayBuffer = reader.result;

                sendImage(fileContentArrayBuffer, fileType);
            });

            if (imageFile) {
                //save the mime type of the file
                fileType = imageFile.type;

                //read the file asynchronously
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(imageFile);
            }   
        });

        function sendImage(fileContentArrayBuffer, fileType) {

            $.ajax({
                // NOTE: You must use the same location in your REST call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.
                //   For example, if you obtained your subscription keys from westcentralus, replace "westus" in the 
                //   URL below with "westcentralus".
                url: "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/",
                beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                    // Request headers, also supports "application/octet-stream"
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");

                    // NOTE: Replace the "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" value with a valid subscription key.
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","my key");
                },
                //don't forget this!
                processData: false,
                type: "POST",
                // Request body
                data: new Blob([fileContentArrayBuffer], { type: fileType })
            }).done(function(data) {
                alert(data);
                // Get face rectangle dimensions
                var faceRectangle = data[0].faceRectangle;
                var faceRectangleList = $('#faceRectangle');

                // Append to DOM
                for (var prop in faceRectangle) {
                    faceRectangleList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + faceRectangle[prop] + "</li>");
                }

                // Get emotion confidence scores
                var scores = data[0].scores;
                var scoresList = $('#scores');

                // Append to DOM
                for(var prop in scores) {
                    scoresList.append("<li> " + prop + ": " + scores[prop] + "</li>")
                }
            }).fail(function(err) {
                alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
            });
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your key, the request URL for Emotion API should be
`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize?`

You may also want to take a look at [this website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2016/03/07/using-the-project-oxford-emotion-api-in-c-and-javascript/). It got similar code.

Sorry I can't use comment function as I am new here and don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I couldn't find an option to register for emotion api. I found face api, and it also gave me the domain `westcentralus`.

Comment: @omega Sorry for the confusion, I mean `recognize?` after your URL. Also, according to the webpage, Face API now integrates emotion recognition capability in general availability. See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/emotion-api/) (the blue notice).

Comment: I tried `https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/recognize?` but it has the same error.

Comment: Emotion API is not demised yet. If you want to use Face API, make sure you follow this [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/javascript). Be careful of the `param` part. If you use Emotion API, check your URL. Its `...microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/...` as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/emotion/quickstarts/javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Could you double check with your api region? Because this error occurs when there is no resource found for given api key in a region.
And for accessing emotions you will need to pass parameters to api which will give you attributes for faces in response which contains emotions.